# Admob. Disable specific ad network

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have an app with advertising monetization strategy. My advertising is based on mediation algorithms with several advertising networks:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:9.15.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:tapjoy:12.8.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:chartboost:8.2.0.0'
```

The problem is in Chartboost. It crashes all the time when users with 5.0 and 5.1 Android OS are requesting ads from Chartboost:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError
Verifier rejected class w.d.a.l.a due to bad method void w.d.a.l.a.run() (declaration of 'w.d.a.l.a' appears in /data/app/com.ilyin.alchemy-1/base.apk)
com.chartboost.sdk.Tracking.e.f (e.java:8)
com.chartboost.sdk.Tracking.e.e (e.java:3)
com.chartboost.sdk.j$a.a (j.java:4)
com.chartboost.sdk.impl.p0.a (p0.java:85)
com.chartboost.sdk.Networking.l.run (l.java:6)
```

I want to avoid this crash. If you know way to provide Charboost's ads for Lollipop's users without crash, I'd like to know it too.

But I think it is impossible. So I also looking for option to disable Charboost from mediation for Lollipops programmatically.

Comment: Hello, do you find any solution? I am looking for the same thing (disable specific ad network)

Comment: @gamemn02 sorry, I didn't find the solution. I disabled all the networks excepting AdMob

Comment: Create two ad units in AdMob. In first ad unit, add all networks and in the second ad unit, add the networks you want. In the add, check the user's SDK version. If it is 5.0 or 5.1, load the second ad unit, else load the first ad unit.